# How can I name a container in Castle Windsor?

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

In a project for work I've determined that child containers are a better approach (from a logical standpoint) than Typed Factories to do what we need to do.

I've created configuration for multiple child containers to be added to the root container. However, I need to be able to choose a child container at runtime and use that for injection based on our business context. As such, each container should be identified by the business context name (in our WebAPI WindsorCompositionRoot).

It looks as though Castle won't allow me to set a name when I construct a container. The one overload that does allow a name seems to attempt to pull from XML configuration, which is not what I want. (I don't know if there's something missing there.) The `name` property is a getter, with no setter, so I can't set the name after instantiation.

How can I name a container so that I can pull it easily with `GetChildContainer`? Due to the way our project is structured, attempting to keep a reference to the child container (or even return it) would be somewhat painful - and, likely, a poor design.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this ? I've the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

To create a Windsor container with name, you can use the below constructor by passing DefaultKernel and DefaultComponentsInstaller as arguments

```
public WindsorContainer(string name, IKernel kernel, IComponentsInstaller installer)
```

Sample code to invoke the above constructor

```
new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer(containerName, new DefaultKernel(), new DefaultComponentInstaller())
```

**Note:** DefaultKernel and DefaultComponentInstaller will be used when you create a windsor container with default constructor